# What are my xAxis labels misaligned?

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to highcharts and I'm just trying to get a basic line chart up and running.  When I set xaxis label step my labels become misaligned. I'm using  v3.0.5. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtFy9/) Anyone know why?

[image]

```
 $(elementSelector).highcharts({
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled:false  
    },
    chart: {
        type: chartType
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: sectionData.XAxisLabel
        },
        labels: {
            step: sectionData.XAxisLabelSkip
        },
        categories: xpoints 
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: sectionData.YAxisLabel
        },
        min: 0,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        title:'',
        data: ypoints,
        showInLegend: false
    }]
});
```

Comment: you sure it's not a bug in the version you use? What version are you using? Have you tried another one?

Comment: sectionData.XAxisLabelSkip must be a number

Comment: I'm using v3.0.5, I will try different version.

Comment: you could also try defining a width for the labels: formatter: labels: {
                style:{
                    width:'75px',
                },
                step: sectionData.XaxisLabelSkip
            }

Comment: can you try and replace your variables with straight values? it helps you and us to see what it really gets into those properties

Comment: Could you replicate your example in the jsfiddle.net, because without all variables we cannto replroduce this issue.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks for the help.  Here is the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/rtFy9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice to remove " 2013" elements in array and use tickInterval instead of step.

```
tickInterval:4,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rtFy9/1/